# Checking conditions (date, time) with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, conditional-statements

I need to check if the current time is within a certain range of fields within the DB.

For example in the DB I would store a `start time`, `end time`, `start date`, and `end date`.

I then need to check if the current date is within the rage of values returned by the query.

I have attempted:

```
WHERE start_date <= $currdate 
  AND end_date >= $currdate
  AND start_time <= $currtime
  AND end_time >= $currtime
```

Which works great, until we get a situation where the dates overlap two days, in which case the query returns `NULL` as `end_time` is obviously LESS than the current time.

I guess I need a way to combine `start_date` and `start_time` with `end_date` and `end_time`?

Comment: Add the full working query, test data and expected results, it will help to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Is this an existing data model you have to work with, or are you proposing it?  It would be trivial to solve this if you had start_datetime and end_datetime columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried timestamp()?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp

Perhaps can do something like

```
WHERE timestamp(start_date, start_time) <= timestamp(currdate, currtime)
  AND timestamp(end_date, end_time) >= timestamp(currdate, currtime)
```

This is assuming, of course, that your start/end date and time are related.  Not fully sure what the business logic is behind separating those two fields...